# Errors on maven project, but no errors showing on files or pom

Tags: java, maven, project

[image: folder and file structure]

I am getting an error symbol on my project as you can see from the image, however there are no errors within the files. i have tried updating maven, and i have checked the pom and there are also no errors in here.

Comment: Has the ["error" window](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-error_log_view.htm) something that could help?

Comment: @Tom no it doesnt seem to be showing any errors. I look at the error window after updating maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At times it shows error symbol even though the project does not contain a single error, and more interestingly the project however **works fine** even with the error symbol. That's the case with me in various maven projects.

Comment: I think it's looking like this is the case

Comment: So does that solve your query?

Comment: well i still have the errors but like you said, the project still works fine. So I don't think i need to worry, it would be nice if i could get rid of the symbol though.

Comment: I think I found out the reason behind that error symbol.
Please follow this:
In your eclipse project go to 
Window-->Show View-->Problems
In the Problems section you will be able to see the errors. If you solve those you can get rid of the error symbol

Comment: aah okay i see them, thanks sagar panda i'll resolve them now and let you know if it works